# Do all layers have the same computational complexity in a ResNet?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

Reading the [ResNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05027v3.pdf), paragraph 3.3:

> The convolutional layers mostly have 3×3 filters and follow two simple
>   design rules: (i) for the same output feature map size, the layers
>   have the same number of filters; and (ii) if the feature map size is
>   halved, the number of filters is doubled so as to preserve the time
>   complexity per layer.

The network uses convolutional layers with stride 2 to halve the feature map size, but this divides both the width and the height of the feature maps, so the total area is divided by 4, not by 2.

So I am guessing the time complexity per layer is halved every time the feature maps are halved. Did I miss something?